# Execute custom code when user makes one of the Sequencer's clips(Sequence) active

Tags: python, video-sequence-editor

I am trying to find a way to catch an event when user clicks on the video clip on the timeline in Sequencer and make it active. I basically want to run some custom code every time that happens.

I tried to use MSGBUS to capture that event, but it doesn't recognize the event.
I was thinking of using Update function, but they seem to work only for custom properties.

Basically what would be the best way to catch when bpy.context.scene.sequence_editor.active_strip changes value? Or when bpy.context.active_sequence_strip changes value.

Thank you so much for any help or suggestions!

Maciej

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I tried using a `bpy.apps.handler` on `depsgraph_upgrade_post` but evidently the depsgraph is not updated when an object is just made active.

So I went with making a custom property for the scene and then setting the `active_strip.as_pointer()` as a string property for the scene and then setting a time to check if this value has changed every .2 seconds.

Seems to work ok. Idk how likely it is to affect performance, probably not horrible but not the best case scenario either ¯_(ツ)_/¯ .

````
import bpy

class ActiveStripProps(bpy.types.PropertyGroup):
    active_strip_id: bpy.props.StringProperty()
    

def active_sequence_strip_change():
    active_strip = bpy.context.scene.sequence_editor.active_strip
    if active_strip is not None:
        active_strip_id = str(active_strip.as_pointer())
        props = bpy.context.scene.active_strip_props
        strip_id = props.active_strip_id
        if strip_id != active_strip_id:
            print("Active strip has changed.")
            props.active_strip_id = active_strip_id
    return 0.2


def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(ActiveStripProps)
    bpy.types.Scene.active_strip_props = bpy.props.PointerProperty(type=ActiveStripProps)
    bpy.context.scene.active_strip_props.active_strip_id = "0"
    bpy.app.timers.register(active_sequence_strip_change)
    
def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(ActiveStripProps)
    del bpy.types.Scene.active_strip_props
    bpy.app.timers.unregister(active_sequence_strip_change)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    
    register()
```
````

Comment: Ohhhh....that is very interesting! Thank you so much @Jakemoyo! I will give it a shot!

Comment: So I tried the code and I am running into a little issue, probably because I don't have enough knowledge about how app.timers work. Basically I tried to put my own function to run after print("Active strip has changed.") line of your code. What I noticed is that sometimes my function gets called, but sometimes it doesn't get called at all. Any suggestions how to make sure that my function would be called? Thanks in advance for any tips!

Comment: Ahhh...never mind, I realized that I run my script several times in the same blender session probably creating multiple app timers competing with each other. Restarting blender and running my code just once solved the problem!

Comment: Awesome, yeah there's also a [method to remove timers](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.app.timers.html#bpy.app.timers.unregister) as well. FYI.